# Searching closest venues using ll and radius not working properly

Tags: foursquare

I know there are a lot of questions about this issue, but I've reached a point where I can't really do anything else but to ask if somebody else has a solution for this issue...

Using the Foursquare api explorer to test out my query I can't seem to obtain an accurate or even good fit for the data I need to obtain.

It is quite simple. **I need to obtain the closest venue from a set of coordinates.** I don't mind not having results if nothing is found near by.

So, reading the API documentation (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) I conclude that I need a search and not an explore because I don't want sugestions of recommended venues (and the results when I tested it proved that it wasn't what I was expecting).

So, using search api I want to find places (the place, but places would do...) close to these coordinates

> ll=37.424782,-122.162989

considering that I want places close by, I add

> radius=51

and I don't really want many results

> limit=2

from the documentation I see that radius is

> Only valid for requests with intent=browse, or requests with
>   intent=checkin and categoryId or query

so, I use

> intent=browse

which concludes my query to: 
venues/search?intent=browse&ll=37.424782,-122.162989&radius=51&limit=2

Query Result:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fintent%3Dbrowse%26ll%3D37.424782,-122.162989%26radius%3D51%26limit%3D2

**Here we can see that the first result is straight outside of the radius ... distance: 135**
the second result however is cool ... distance: 50

What am I doing wrong to get these results? If I increase the limit all I get is more results that are also outside the radius, I could iterate through them and find the one with the smallest distance... but I have no guarantee that the closest result will be on the top X that I limit, even If I had that guarantee, it would be a tiresome solution to an apparently simple question...

Thanks for the help...
Marc

---

EDIT:

---

I managed to make have the query perform as I intended ... But I had to add all of the parent categories from:

https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree

```
categoryId=
4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,  Arts & Entertainment
4d4b7105d754a06372d81259,  College & University
4d4b7105d754a06373d81259,  Event
4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,  Food
4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,  Nightlife Spot
4d4b7105d754a06377d81259,  Outdoors & Recreation
4d4b7105d754a06375d81259,  Professional & Other Places
4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a,  Residence
4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,  Shop & Service
4d4b7105d754a06379d81259   Travel & Transport
```

making my query into:
venues/search?

> intent=checkin&ll=37.424782,-122.162989&radius=60&categoryId=4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,4d4b7105d754a06372d81259,4d4b7105d754a06373d81259,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,4d4b7105d754a06377d81259,4d4b7105d754a06375d81259,4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a,4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,4d4b7105d754a06379d81259

Query Result:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fintent%3Dcheckin%26ll%3D37.424782,-122.162989%26radius%3D60%26categoryId%3D4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,4d4b7105d754a06372d81259,4d4b7105d754a06373d81259,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,4d4b7105d754a06377d81259,4d4b7105d754a06375d81259,4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a,4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,4d4b7105d754a06379d81259

**It still has results outside of my radius still ... but it's an acceptable error margin ... it is weird however.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make have the query perform as I intended ... But I had to add all of the parent categories from:

https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree

categoryId=
4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,  Arts & Entertainment
4d4b7105d754a06372d81259,  College & University
4d4b7105d754a06373d81259,  Event
4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,  Food
4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,  Nightlife Spot
4d4b7105d754a06377d81259,  Outdoors & Recreation
4d4b7105d754a06375d81259,  Professional & Other Places
4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a,  Residence
4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,  Shop & Service
4d4b7105d754a06379d81259   Travel & Transport
making my query into: venues/search?

intent=checkin&ll=37.424782,-122.162989&radius=60&categoryId=4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,4d4b7105d754a06372d81259,4d4b7105d754a06373d81259,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,4d4b7105d754a06377d81259,4d4b7105d754a06375d81259,4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a,4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,4d4b7105d754a06379d81259

Query Result: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fintent%3Dcheckin%26ll%3D37.424782,-122.162989%26radius%3D60%26categoryId%3D4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,4d4b7105d754a06372d81259,4d4b7105d754a06373d81259,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,4d4b7105d754a06377d81259,4d4b7105d754a06375d81259,4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a,4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,4d4b7105d754a06379d81259

It still has results outside of my radius still ... but it's an acceptable error margin ... it is weird however.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old I'm responding for others. I was working on something similar to this recently and what I learned was that in order to use radius you also need to use the 'query' parameter. What I did was to use the star character '*' and it worked for me. I have to say though that the limit of 50 is something I haven't solved yet which I'm working on at the moment.